# React prevent add if exists

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm making a small project in react, and I have teams and meetings.
I need to prevent add of a new meeting to a certain team if this team has a meeting at that time.
How can I do that?
Also, how is it possible to block past dates with this input type?
Thank you!

```
function Insert(): JSX.Element {

const navigate = useNavigate();

const [teams, setTeams] = useState<TeamModel[]>([]);

const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<MeetingModel>();

useEffect(() => {
    meetingsService.getAllTeams()
        .then(teams => setTeams(teams))
        .catch(err => alert(err.message));
}, []);

async function send(meeting: MeetingModel) {
    try {
        await meetingsService.addMeeting(meeting);
        alert("Meeting has been added");
        navigate("/meetings");
    }
    catch (err: any) {
        alert(err.message);
    }
}
return (
    <div className="Insert">
        <h2>Add Meeting</h2>

        <img src={teamImage} alt="Team work" />

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(send)}>

            <label>Select Team: </label>
            <select defaultValue="" {...register("teamId")} required>
                <option disabled value="">
                    Select Team
                </option>
                {teams.map(t => <option key={t.teamId} value={t.teamId}>{t.teamName}</option>)}
            </select>

            <label>Start of meeting:</label>
            <input type="datetime-local" {...register("meetingStart")} required />

            <label>End of meeting: </label>
            <input type="datetime-local" {...register("meetingEnd")} required />

            <label>Description: </label>
            <input type="text" {...register("description")} required min="1" max="100" />

            <label>Meeting room: </label>
            <input type="text" {...register("meetingRoom")} required min="1" max="100" />

            <button>Add</button>
        </form>

    </div>
);
```

Comment: You can add an if check in the try catch above the ` .addMeeting(meeting)`. Check that the meeting does not exist or else throw an error message or something else.